# How do I pass Foreign key value in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRGi.jpg)

How do I access savedata.project_detail in views.py?
Each user will have as many projects as he wants. Each project will have one unique primary key. I wan to access that primary key in def checklist(request) function.
I only get model attribute "checked_value" from html template. The other attribute "project_detail" should automatically fetch primary key pf model "project". But I don't know how to fetch primary key of model project in def checklist function. If anyone can help here.

Here is models.py

```
class project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class check_done(models.Model):
    checked_value = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    project_detail = models.ForeignKey(project, to_field="id", db_column="project_detail", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is views.py

```
def show(request):
    log_user = request.user
    projects = project.objects.filter(user=log_user)
    return render(request, 'project.html',{'p':projects})

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST['data']
        new = project(project_name = data, user=request.user)
        new.save()
        return render(request, 'addproject.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'addproject.html')

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def checklist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            savedata = check_done()
            savedata.project_detail = ??
            print(savedata.project_detail)
            savedata.checked_value = request.POST.get('abc')
            savedata.save()
            return render(request, 'checklist.html')
            
    else:
        return render(request, 'checklist.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a project model to savedata.project_detail attribute:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def checklist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        savedata = check_done()
        savedata.project_detail = project.objects.get(id=request.POST['project_detail_id'])
        savedata.checked_value = request.POST.get('abc')
        savedata.save()
        return render(request, 'checklist.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'checklist.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create or fetch `project` object which you want to associate with the the `savedata` object and assign it directly to the `project_detail` attribute, or you could assign the project primary key to the `project_detail_id` attribute.

Comment: I am sorry but the answer is still not clear to me. Can you elaborate it? Or perhaps you can write syntax? @IliaNovoselov

Comment: See Carlo's answer